# Serial port can't send the response - Python3 and PySerial

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial, uart

I have two python scripts that are communicating with each other: script 1 (running on port 0) sends out a list of transmit messages, print them in first terminal, and script 2 (running on port 1) prints the transmit messages sent to it and should send back responses to the transmit messages.

Almost everything works fine when I am sending the messages only. The thing is that port 1 can't send the response to the transmit messages to port 0.

Each transmit UART message expects a certain (hard-coded) response to be sent (for now, they have the same array index numbers, but I should find a better solution for this).

In short:

1) Port 1 should send an answer to port 0, but it's missing.

2) All printed messages on the port 1 end are written in one line and it's hard to read them (some bytes are missing/can't be printed properly). Should I use a better solution than built-in Xubuntu terminal or change my code?

3) All hex values from the array of arrays (items in message arrays) are printed in decimal, although they are properly forwarded to the port 1 as hex values. I wonder why this is happening. None of the attempts to convert the print values to hex worked.

Sorry if I didn't explain what I mean properly or if the solution already exists. Here are the most important parts of the code (I added just a couple of messages, so you can get the idea).

**Transmit script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from crc_calc import CRC8

import serial
import time
import sys

port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
baudrate = 115200
bytesize = 'EIGHTBITS'
parity = 'PARITY_NONE'
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200,  timeout=1, 
      write_timeout=5)

msg_set_101 = [0xCA, 0x00, 0x04, 0x10, 0x01, 0x18, 0x01]
msg_set_false101 = [0xCA, 0x00, 0x04, 0x10, 0x01, 0x18, 0x04]

sec_msg = [msg_set_101, msg_set_false101]

def is_open():
    if ser.isOpen():
        print("Port is open at " + ser.name)
    else:
        print("Port " + ser.name + " is closed")


def send_with_crc(sec_msg):
    for i in sec_msg:
        result_crc = CRC_calc.calculate(i)
        print("calculated CRC: 0x%x" % result_crc)
        i.append(result_crc)
        new_result_crc = CRC_calc.calculate(i)
        print("final calculated CRC: 0x%x" % new_result_crc)
        print(i)
        ser.write(i)

def show_res_sec():
    while 1:
        msg = ser.readline()
        print(msg)

is_open()

send_with_crc(sec_msg)

show_res_sec()
```

**Receive script**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import serial
import time

port2 = "/dev/ttyUSB1"
baudrate = 115200
bytesize = 'EIGHTBITS'
parity = 'PARITY_NONE'

ser2 = serial.Serial(port=port2, baudrate=115200, timeout=1, 
       writeTimeout=5)


res_set_101 = [0xCA, 0x00, 0x04, 0x80, 0x01, 0x28, 0x00]
res_set_false101 = [0xCA, 0x00, 0x04, 0x80, 0x01, 0x18, 0x01]

msg_res = [res_set_101, res_set_false101]

def is_open2():
    if ser2.isOpen():
        print("Port is open at " + ser2.name)

is_open2()

time.sleep(2)

counter = 0


def send_sec(msg_res):
    for i in msg_res:
        print(i)
        ser.write(i)


def receive_msg():
    while 1:
        msg = ser2.readline()
        print(msg)


receive_msg()

send_sec(msg_res)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your reading method is not working because **ser2.readline()** is waiting for **"/n"** so after calculating your CRC you can add **"/n"** or you can use ser2.read(number of bytes you are waiting for).

```
...     s = ser.read(10)        # read up to ten bytes (timeout)
...     line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
```

Hope it works for you =)